# Axios 'Get' Function Not Calling

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

So, I am wanting to retrieve an updated list of contacts on once a new contact is added. Unfortunately, axios is only loading the get request on the 'beforeMount()' instance. When I try and call the function inside of an axios.post request when it's successful, the list of contacts is gone until I refresh the page again.

I'm running Laravel 5.7 and VueJs 2.5.22.

```
 import axios from 'axios';

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        companion: {
          name: '',
          desc: '',
          primaryPhone: '',
          secondaryPhone: '',
          email: '',
          address: '',
          notes: '',
          image: ''
    },
    characterAmount: 0
  };
},
props: {
  addCompanion: {
    type: Boolean
  }
},
methods: {
  checkNotesLength(e) {
    this.characterAmount = 
    document.getElementById('notes').value.length;

    if (e.keyCode === 8) {
      this.characterAmount--;
      if (this.characterAmount < 0) {
        this.characterAmount = 0;
      }
    } else {
      this.characterAmount++;
      if (this.characterAmount > 150) {
        this.characterAmount = 150;
      }
    }
  },
  processFile(e) {
    var input = e.target;
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e) => {
      this.companion.image = e.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  },
  getCompanions() {
    const url = window.location + 'companions';

    axios.get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        this.companions = response.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
  submitCompanion() {
    const formData = {
      name: this.companion.name,
      desc: this.companion.desc,
      primaryPhone: this.companion.primaryPhone,
      secondaryPhone: this.companion.secondaryPhone,
      email: this.companion.email,
      address: this.companion.address,
      notes: this.companion.notes,
      image: this.companion.image
    }
    axios.post('/companion/create', formData)
    .then(this.getCompanions())
    .then((response) => {
      this.addCompanion = !this.addCompanion;
      //need to clear form and include messages, also need to add validation
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
}
```

The beforeMount() function is on my App.vue, which just calls the same getCompanions function as the above one you see.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that I see in your code is that you are not passing the callback correctly. This code will execute the function `getCompanions()` immediately:

```
.then(this.getCompanions())
```

To pass it as a callback try something like this

```
.then(this.getCompanions.bind(this))
// OR
.then(() => this.getCompanions())
```

Comment: Ahh, makes sense. I did add this change in, but unfortunately the issue continues. Still writing to the database correctly, but not refreshing.

Comment: @valtro05 Do you see the `get` request in the developer tool network tab?

Comment: Yep - looks like it went through fine and carried the data with it. I'm baffled to be honest, lol.

Comment: @valtro05 Sounds like the original issue of the request not going through is fixed. I am not sure what do you expect to happen after loading the champions list. I am not a Vue expert but the `champions` property is not defined in the `data()` factory so it might not be reactive. If you can't figure out what the other bugs in your code are I suggest opening a new question.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your url structure is wrong.

```
const url = window.location + 'companions';
```

should be

```
const url = window.location + '/companions';
```

Comment: When you console.log the response.data  for const url = window.location + 'companions'; do you get any output ?

Comment: Yep, all the data is there and the url is correct. Passing the data doesn't seem to be the problem. The problem seems to be the get request not being called again.